# "Такой, как" и "Такой, какой"

Tags: союзы, союзные-слова

```
1. Я такой, как Вася. 
2. Я такой, какой Вася.
```

Есть ли смысловая разница между этими предложениями? Является ли **как** союзом или союзным словом и почему?

Если **как** союзное слово, то почему оно отвечает на вопрос какой?  Если это союз, то почему предворяется указательным местоимением?

Comment: Второе предложение бессмысленно.

Answer (score 1):

Сложноподчиненные предложения, оформленные посредством **союзного слова**. АГ-1980, п. 2887, 2880.

```
Я такой, какой Вася.
Я из тех, какой Вася.
Цветы те, каких не найти.
```

Союзные предложения оформленные **союзом** как. АГ-1980, п. 2833. п. 2830, 2831.

```
Мыслитель, как вы, ... // в 19 веке было нормой не добавлять "такой"    
Мыслитель такой, как вы, ... // уточнение союзной связи
```